# an array in python displayed using elements in qml

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I should display some rects with qml. 
These Rectangle{} the positiopn of those depend on x=array[i][0] and y=array[i][1], and the quantity of those depend on array.lenght().

**array in qml should be equal to self.__rectanglePos in Python**

So I need a way to draw Rectangle in a different position and in different amount that depends array.

how can I do that?

_____.py

```
class NN(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.__rectanglePos = [] #each element contains:[x,y,orientation 360°]

    #signals
    rectanglePosChanged = Signal(type(self.__rectanglePos))

    @Slot()
    def rects(self):   
        self.rectanglePosChanged.emit(self.__rectanglePos)   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qmlRegisterType(NN, 'gnn', 1, 0, 'NN')
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(gnn.qml))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is not working in qml:
________.qml

```
#[...]
import gnn 1.0


ApplicationWindow {
     ListView{
            id: rect
            function f(){
                for (var i = 0; i < array.lenght(); ++i){
                     Rectangle {      
                          x: array[i][0]
                          y: array[i][1]
                     }
                }                  
            }
    }
    MouseArea{
    onClicked: rects()
    }
    NN{
        id: nn

        signal getRectangles(var array) // not working

        Component.onCompleted: {

            nn.rectanglePosChanged.connect(getRectangles)

        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: nn

        onGetRectangles: {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I see that item in the array has 3 elements. What information does these 3 elements provide? I ask because your code is confusing and you indicate that it represents the information of a rectangle

Comment: The array contains the position of the rectangle (x,y) and an other element that let me know if the element is considered or not, but the last one is not important for the question. if you read the python code, you can see self.__rectanglePos #[x, y, 360°], that is an element of the array. For instance the array can contain: [[0.5,0.5, 180],[1,0,45],[0.3,0.8,0], .. ]. the amount of element [ [],[], .. ] is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has many errors, for example you want to access an attribute of the class: `self.__rectanglePos)` which only makes sense when creating an object from a part of the code that is executed before creating the class: `rectanglePosChanged = Signal(type(self.__rectanglePos))`, so I will avoid pointing out what your errors are except those necessary for my solution.

If you want to send information as a list where you add, replace or remove items then it is better to use a model as it will notify you in view of the changes. In this case for simplicity I use a QStandardItemModel, so each part of the element as "x" and "y" will be accessed through roles.

In the case of QML, as you want to place Rectangles in any position, using ListView is not the right option since this view restricts the position, instead you must use a Repeater.

**main.py**

```py
import os
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml

XRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
YRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001
AngleRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1002


class RectangleManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        roles = {XRole: b"x", YRole: b"y", AngleRole: b"angle"}

        self.m_model.setItemRoleNames(roles)

    @QtCore.Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self.m_model

    @QtCore.Slot(float, float, float)
    def add_rectangle(self, x, y, angle):
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it.setData(x, XRole)
        it.setData(y, YRole)
        it.setData(angle, AngleRole)
        self.model.appendRow(it)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def clear_rectangles(self):
        self.model.clear()


def main(args):
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(args)

    manager = RectangleManager()

    import random

    for _ in range(10):
        manager.add_rectangle(
            random.randint(0, 500), random.randint(0, 500), random.randint(0, 360)
        )

    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("rectangle_manager", manager)
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        return -1
    ret = app.exec_()
    return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Repeater{
        model: rectangle_manager.model

        Rectangle{
            x: model.x
            y: model.y
            rotation: model.angle
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The code is readapted to simplify it since the original is really long and complex.
I should use **"qmlRegisterType(NN, 'gnn', 1, 0, 'NN')"**, but I'm not able to use it. 
Also, is it possible to delete all the items created? like with ".clear()"?

Comment: @DavideFaggian 1) I understand that you want to place the information from python but if you use qmlRegisterType you will not be able to. 2) I have already added the clear function.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do you think is possible to use both setContextProperty and qmlRegisterType? since A lot of the program is already done with qmlRegisterType.

Comment: @DavideFaggian You cannot use both. Each of these methods has its objective. In the case of setContextProperty it is to export a C++/Python object to QML(that is to say create and modify it in python), instead qmlRegisterType registers a class written in C++/Python (that is, it is implemented in C++/Python  but not instantiated or modified) in QML. I recommend you understand what each method, class, function, etc. you want to use works for, that others use in their examples does not imply that you should use it in your project.

Comment: Thank you. I have alredy mark it as correct. What's the meaning of these:
XRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
YRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001
AngleRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1002

Comment: @DavideFaggian 1) You still haven't marked it as correct 2) Read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Comment: I'm still not understanding how "XRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000 YRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001 AngleRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1002 " work and how should I use it

Comment: @DavideFaggian read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#item-roles